# Script for running sequential job

Tags: bash, command-line, shell-script, cluster

I started recently to learn using Linux. I want to write a script in bash shell to run a serial job on a cluster. I have been searching for hints and instructions on how to write such a script. I managed to write the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -l walltime=1:00:00
#PBS -e test.err
#PBS -o test.log
cd /home/myuser/
echo "Running on host `hostname`"
echo "Time is `date`"
echo "Directory is `pwd`"
/home/myuser/comsol4.3b/bin/comsol batch -inputfile DF.mph -outputfile output.mph -batchlog out.log
```

The last line calls the program (it is called COMSOL) to run. One of the things that are missing in my code is the command “qsub”; I don’t know how to incorporate it with the rest of commands in my code. Can anyone please instruct me how to modify the line that calls the program I am using by “qsub” command please?

Sorry if my question is so simple, I spent a lot of time trying to make it work but I couldn’t unfortunately.

**EDIT**: To summarize, if I typed the last line of the code ONLY it will be run on the main node only, I don't want that. What I want is to modify  the last line of the code such that it uses the resources I allocated to it using PBS lines, how should I do that?

For the record, the command `qhost` shows there are 250 nodes with varying cores per node from 4 cores/node to 16 cores/node

Comment: You want to submit this job multiple times, changing something about it as part of each submission? If you're using PBS or GrdEngine they typically provide you a facility called arrays that can be used to do this. You can also call `qsub` like so: qsub jobX.bash 1234`. The `1234` argument could be parameterized and fed via a for loop. We'd need to see more of the actual array of values to help further.

Comment: No it isn't an array. I don't want to change anything. I want the job to use the resources I allocated to it by PBS lines. If I only typed the last line of the code it will run on the main node only. I don't want that, what I want is running it on many nodes as I can specify using "qsub" or PBS scheduler. My question is simply, what command should I write to make the code run on allocated resources rather than the main node only?? Do you think I should write that in my question for clarification? @slm

Comment: Yes include that in the Q please. Can you explain what other nodes there are? You typically use the command `qhost` to find the other nodes. You can either submit to them directly or select a common attribute that they all have (2GB RAM) or something similar. Generally though the `qsub` command should automatically submit your job to any node. I would seek out your administrator of your cluster if this isn't working like that.

Comment: Thank you @slm I modefied the question. The problem is that 'qsub' command is not included in my code as you see. I believe that is the starting point to fix it.

Comment: If the script you wrote is in the file foo.sh, then you want to give the command `qsub foo.sh` to submit it to the batch system.  It will then be routed onto one of the execute nodes with the resources you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specifically say which clustering software you're using, but based on the fact you're asking about `qsub`, I know that both GridEngine (and derivatives) along with PBS use that particular command, so let's start with those.

I'm most familiar with GridEngine (and derivatives) so to submit a command using that package you'd do something like this.

Example

Here's a sample script, we'll call it `sample.bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Working directory is $PWD"
```

To submit this script, you do the following:

```
$ qsub sample.bash
```

To target specific nodes within the cluster you'll need to include attributes that are unique to a set of these nodes, so that the GridEngine scheduling software can pick one of these nodes, and run your job on one of them.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is useful. Until now when I wanted to run the script I used to type 'bash sample.sh' is that different from running the script using qsub?? And one more thing please, what attributes should I look for to use particular nodes? I am sorry for those naive questions @slm

Comment: @Gotaquestion - that is different. Running `bash sample.sh` runs the script on the current box. Running via `qsub` will submit the script to the head node, which will then farm it out to one of the worker nodes. Attributes will be things like RAM, OS levels, etc.

Comment: @Gotaquestion - what cluster software are you using?

Comment: The cluster software is Son of Grid Engine which is a continouation of old Sun grid engine @slm

Comment: It is SGE 8.1.6 in particular

Comment: @Gotaquestion - you can use the commands `qstat` and `qhost` to see the hosts. I think if memory serves me right, you can use the command `qstat -F` to get a full list of attributes or `qhost -F`.

Comment: You are correct, thank you very much for your help @slm